# Database Iterators in Conjunction with Paging

Tags: scala, iterator

my question is of a conceptual nature but very important to me:

When using databases you typically get an iterator back from the query containing the resultset. However: when you want to do paging, you wanna be able to move that resultset back and forth. this is however not possible using an iterator. so the naive idea here would be to use a conversion to list. but that again  takes a time of O(n) which can cause a serious problem performance wise.

Im sure there must be a solution to this problem (other than using elasticsearch :D ).
What's the best method of approaching this problem?

with best regards,

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

You want paging, but you don't want to do an `O(n)` loading of your unpaged result set into memory. Fair enough - logically that implies that the database must hand you paged chunks. I think most RDMS databases have something like 'LIMIT' and 'OFFSET' SQL:

```
select id, name from foo where date > ? LIMIT $start, $page_size;
```

If you were dealing with MySQL, and were writing raw SQL, then it would be something like that.  But with libraries such as Slick, you could have

```
val query = for { 
  d <- Parameter[Date]
  f <- foo if f.date > d
} yield (f.id, f.name)
```

So to get all rows unpaged you do

```
query(yesterday).list
// Select id, name from foo
```

And if you want paging, it's simple:

```
query(yesterday).drop(20).take(5).list
// Select id, name from foo limit 20, 5 ; %% whatever; I suck at SQL and can't remember syntac

                                          %% but you get the point.
```

Which will return a list of `(Id, Name)`, of 5 elements, assuming your want only 5 per page. That means this subsequence will be the 5th page of results.

Not that this is what you'd likely do if instead of `query(yesterday)` you had a `List` of results in memory: SLICK provides you with an abstraction for queries, a `Query` type that 
contains many useful methods usually found in collections. The `.list` method is what actually executes the final query to get you a `List[T]` (in this example `List[(Int, String)]`) but before calling it you can 'page' your results (by calling `.take`, `drop` etc, that build uopn the original query) and in this example the SQL does the paging for you
and SLICK generates that SQL so you just do `.take`, `.drop` or whatever.

It helps if your model layer takes advantage of SLICK's composability: you define 
basic queries in SLICK instead of writing raw SQL and these queries are usable as building blocks for others queries.

Comment: Slick does not always generate the most optimal queries, especially for multiple tables.

Comment: Limit and offset doesn't necessarily perform well especially let's say if the cursor is very huge. As far as I understand it, so drop and take will just translate into that i assume? and also the .list method does exactly what I wanted to prevent?